# JDO Query with cursors on GAE returns same cursor

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, jdo

I'm trying to implement pagination in my GAE queries and this is what I've come to:

```
public JSONArray getDeviceListByTypeWithCursor(String cursorString) {

    PersistenceManager pm = persistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManager();

    Query q = pm.newQuery(MobileDevice.class);
    q.setRange(0, 100);
    if(cursorString != "" && cursorString != null){
        Cursor cursor;
        try{
            cursor = Cursor.fromWebSafeString(cursorString);
            Map<String, Object> extensionMap = HashMap<String, Object>();
            extensionMap.put(JDOCursorHelper.CURSOR_EXTENSION, cursor);
            q.setExtensions(extensionMap);
        }catch(Exception e){
            cursor = null;
        }
    }
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

    List<MobileDevice> results = (List<MobileDevice>) q.execute();
    for (MobileDevice device : results) {
        array.put(device.toJSON());
    }
    Cursor cursor = JDOCursorHelper.getCursor(results);
    cursorString = cursor.toWebSafeString();
    array.put(cursorString);
    return array;
}
```

When I send a null cursorString I get the first 100 results + the new cursor as expected.
However, when I send another request using the new cursor I get the correct results (#101-#200) but the same cursor string.

The datastore has a lot of entities (more than 100000), so this probably isn't due to end of results.

**UPDATE**

I've come to realize this might be due to problems with the Spring framework. We're using Spring 4.2.3 - but I don't see anything online regarding working with Spring and GAE, let alone Spring+GAE+Cursors..

Comment: Did you check if the String is the same in this code, or did you check on the client?

Comment: Both.. It's always the same cursorString, regardless of whether I send a null cursor or not

Comment: `cursorString != ""` is not valid code. It should be `cursorString != null && !cursorString.equals(""))`

Comment: You're right (migrating to Java is difficult sometimes..), but that's not it unfortunately

Comment: Remove `cursor = null` from exception- it should not happen. Put a log statement there to check if you actually have an exception.

Comment: Okay, changed that now.. But that's still not it, the exception doesn't get thrown when I pass a cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've added a `results.size()` call after executing the query (I also removed the loop iterating over the results) and that seemed to solve the problem for me. Hope this helps someone else down the road!